# What's the difference between the Spellbook Magazine and the Fireproof Secret Diary?

Tags: team-fortress-2

What's the difference between these two, game-play or cosmetic wise? It seems you can equip both in the Action slot, but I can't tell if there's really any difference.

Is there a gameplay difference between these two?

Comment: One has words you yell out, the other has words you want to keep private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only particle effects I think check this: